# cfhttp restful get fails

Tags: json, rest, cfhttp

Using CF 9.0.1

My objective is to retrieve a JSON value set from another server and then process the result in subsequent CF statements. The distant server requires a client certificate. Presently, everything appears to work (return code 200) but I am not getting any data.

When I cfdump the result, the structure is present, method defined etc ... just no data. Clearly, I have something wrong.

When I put the URL into IE or another browser, the JSON stream is returned.

Ok, so here is my experiment. (may be a few typos given that I cannot copy/paste at the moment)

```
<!--- block 1 --->
<cfset objSecurity = createObject("java", "java.security.Security") />
<cfset storeProvider = objSecurity.getProvider("Jsave.JCE") />
<cfset objSecurity.removeProvider("Jsave.JCE") />

<!--- block 2 --->
<cfhttp
  url = "https://server.a.b.c/rest/xxx"
  clientcert = "C:\Xy\Z"
  clientCertPassword = "mypass"
  method = "Get"
  result="result"
  resolveurl="yes" throwOnError="true" >

<!--- block 3 --->
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Mimetype" value = "application/json" >
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept-Encoding" value="*" >
<cfhttpparam type="header" type="header" name="TE" value="default;q=0">
</cfhttp>
```

I get the same result if I turn off block 1 and block 3 -- i.e. no errors but no expected data.

The cfdump gives 
  Filecontent .... object of java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream ... Class Name  java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream ... Methods (standard methods)
  Header ... looks normal
  Mimetype ... application/json
  ResponseHeader ... nothing seems abnormal
  status code 200

---

Is there something I need to also do besides making the call. Given that I'm not trying to host a JSON service but rather simply trying to retrieve a value that delivers its answer via JSON, where am I going wrong -- or what unknown setting do I need to make?

I did get errors initially until I added the certificate chain but that has all been corrected.

This is running on Microsoft server, tomcat environment, IIS.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated in how to obtain the intended data values.

Comment: Post the full `cfdump` so that we can try and figure out what's going on. Maybe your request is not returning any data, so HTTP 200 would be suitable, but a `Content-length: 0` header would indicate there's no data to return.